# Arabic characters not accepted in Oracle DB

Tags: linux, oracle, unicode, jboss

his this is database admin

I have a Jboss server with oracle database When I enter the Arabic fonts throung the application the database is not accepting throungh the application ; the arabic charters are also defined ; the operating system is Linux with oracle 10g and Jboss server with j2ee application

Answer (score 0):

Let my do some guessing:

- was the database defined as using unicode?
- does the connecting middleware support unicode?
- are the unicode encodings the same (f.e. UTF-8 for app, middleware, and database)?

Answer (score 0):

Can you enter Arabic characters direct to the database (eg SQLLDR or even a standard insert statement in SQL*Plus) ?
What is the characterset of the database (query NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS)